# In CUDD, how to force a group of variables to stay at the end of the ordering?

Tags: cudd

I have two sets of variables A, B. I would like to enable reordering but ensure that at all times variables A appear *before* the variables of B.
I also want to allow reordering within A, and within B.

(I know how to create two groups A and B with Cudd_MakeTreeNode; my question is about ensuring that B comes last)